# How to set a variable with pressing a button on an html file to the flask server route

Tags: python, html, flask, html-generation, dominate

I've become a bit confused in the middle of this, hope you can help me,

I have a text file similar to the one below:

```
./Video/SetUp
./Video/NewRecordings
./Video/NewRecordings/20160113_151920
./Video/Back Up
./Video/Back Up/FirstLecDraft
./Video/Back Up/FirstTalk
```

I use the python script below (thanks to [Dominate](https://github.com/Knio/dominate)) to populate a html file using the `List` text file mentioned above:

```
import dominate
from dominate.tags import *

doc = dominate.document(title='Dominate your HTML')

with doc.head:
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='style.css')
    script(type='text/javascript', src='script.js')

with doc:
    with div():
        with open('List') as f:
            for line in f:
                li(input(line.title(), type='submit', value='%s' % line,     onclick='self.location.href=\'http://127.0.0.1:5000/{This must be the same as "value" part}\''))

    with div():
        attr(cls='body')

print doc
```

First question: How to pass the value of the `value` field to the rest of the path on `onclick`?

The result must be something like this:

```
<input href="" onclick="self.location.href='http://127.0.0.1:5000/cameradump/2016-01-21" type="submit" value="./cameradump/2016-01-21">
```

and respectively another values for another buttons.

as you can see, the rest of the onclick path after `:5000/`must be exactly the same as the `value` field.

Second question: How can I pass this to the route on flasks' `main.py` file? (e.g when the user presses each button, the value of that button must be set to the route dynamically)

`main.py` is like this for now:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import subprocess
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/{value must be passed here}")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
 ...
```

but it should be like below if the user presses the button `/cameradump/2016-01-21`:

```
...
@app.route("/cameradump/2016-01-21")
def index():
return render_template('index.html')
...
```

or another value according to the button which was pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:**

Do the same way as you do with `value` - use `%`

```
onclick='self.location.href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/%s"' % date
```

If you can't have `"2016-01-21"` in file `"List"` but you have `"/cameradump/2016-01-21"` then you can split it (using `"/"`) and get last element - date.

```
# `line` is `"/cameradump/2016-01-21"`

data = line.split('/')[-1]
```

**Second:**

Read doc about [routing](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#routing)

You can use variables in route to get date

```
@app.route("/cameradump/<date>")
def index(date):
    print("Date:", date)
    return render_template('index.html')
```